# How can I make codes in my web page word wrap into a fixed page-width

Tags: html, css

http://hypergroups.pancakeapps.com/GitHub.html

```
batFile = "E:\\Users\\HyperGroups\\AppData\\Local\\GitHub\\PortableGit_015aa71ef18c047ce8509ffb2f9e4bb0e3e73f13\\git-cmd.bat" ;
```

How can I add something like a markdown scroll bar? and can copy to Mathematica Notebook to evaluate?

---

I add a new line, but I cannot copy to Mathematica to Evaluate now

```
batFile = "E:\\Users\\HyperGroups\\AppData\\Local\\GitHub\\PortableGit_015aa
71ef18c047ce8509ffb2f9e4bb0e3e73f13\\git-cmd.bat" ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to `Input` Class.

It is defined on Line : 19 of `GitHub.css`